# Constrain <li> background color within the <ul> on hover

Tags: css

I have a ul that contains a series of li's with content. On hover the background of the li changes colour.
Problem I'm having is that if the viewport is reduced, causing longer headings to stack, the li hover colour bleeds outside the main ul.

I tried overflow:hidden on the li:hover, thinking this would stop it, but I've obviously misunderstood that as it made no difference.

A simple example is

```css
#secondary-menu {
  background: #007dc5;
  width: 80%;
}

ul#topnav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul#topnav li a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 26px 20px;
}

ul#topnav a.home:hover {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px none;
}

a.cat,
ul#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #e6e7eb;
  color: #007dc5;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondary-menu">
  <ul id="topnav">
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Another Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've set up a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/z44eao79/

So, what is the correct way to ensure that a background hover colour for an li doesn't extend outside the boundaries of the ul?

Comment: @Douwe de Haan, how do you set up the code snippet to run on a question? I made a fiddle because I didn't know!

Comment: When you edit, there is this little icon which allows you to make a snippet (looks like a page with square brackets (`<>`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your approach to avoid fixed padding values:

```css
#secondary-menu {
  background: #007dc5;
  width: 80%;
}

ul#topnav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul#topnav li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul#topnav a.home:hover {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px none;
}

a.cat,
ul#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #e6e7eb;
  color: #007dc5;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondary-menu">
  <ul id="topnav">

    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Another Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z44eao79/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `ul#topnav` rules:

```
ul#topnav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```css
#secondary-menu {
  background: #007dc5;
  width: 80%;
}

ul#topnav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul#topnav li a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 26px 20px;
}

ul#topnav a.home:hover {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px none;
}

a.cat,
ul#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #e6e7eb;
  color: #007dc5;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondary-menu">
  <ul id="topnav">
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Another Long Heading</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 secondary-menu-dropdown col-md-2 col-lg-2 "><a href="#" class="cat">Heading</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So I was on the right track with overflow:hidden, just used it in the wrong place. Learned something new today. Thanks!

Comment: Just realised that has bad effect. In the real world use, those headings give a dropdown menu. overflow:hidden on ul#tonav stops them from being visible

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of your actual menu with the dropdowns?